# Appium problem with connect android emulator (adb.exe/settings_apk-debug.apk)

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium

I installed all the necessary software for python-android coding:

- android studio (SDK Build Tools, Google USB Driver, Google WEb Driver and other)
- Appium
- Appium inspector
  But I have one problem with it:

```
 Original error: 'Command 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 127.0.0.1\:21503 install -g 'C:\\Program Files\\Appium Server GUI\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\io.appium.settings\\apks\\settings_apk-debug.apk'' exited with code 1'; Command output: adb: failed to install C:\Program Files\Appium Server GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk
```

When I try to connect via inspector or python to appium server it throws this error. I note that the device is determined when the command is executed "adb devices".
I also manually checked both files due to which the error, they both exist in the right directories.

I also manually added directories to the necessary system variables (JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME, Path)
And on the advice I installed several versions of Java.

But the emulator still won't start. Tell me, what could be the matter? Windows 10

Comment: [Screen_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y8lV.png)
[Screen_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1TT1.png)
[Screen_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xr4d.png)
[Screen_4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQgo7.png)
[Screen_5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxAf8.png)
[Screen_6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAa7o.png)

I have same screens for my text

Comment: UPD. I was able to run through the android studio emulator. But it doesn't want to run through Memu

Comment: UPD. I tried the version of Android 7.1.2 64 bit modified. but new error:
UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature apksigner.jar.
Fix it the desired file from the directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\34.0.0\lib copied to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools and everything started. I will not demolish the topic, maybe someone will have the same problem. Windows 10, if anything, reinstalled the SDK, it didn’t help, in general, a “crutch” was found.

Comment: Checked if you have enabled developer option in device

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify more details on desired capabilities.

```json
{
"platformName": "android",
"appium:automationName": "UIAutomator2",
"appium:udid": "<your emulator Id>",
}
```

if you want to automate a native application, you can also add

```json
{
"appium:app": "<path to your .apk file>",
"appium:appPackage": "<Your application package>",
"appium:appActivity": "<Your app activity>"
}
```

or, if you want to automate a web appication.

```json
{
"browserName": "chrome"
}
```

You can read more [here](https://appium.io/docs/en/2.0/guides/caps/).

Furthermore, it is a good practice to install the latest cli tools.

[image]